# problem with displaying a stored image from storage/app/public/uploads

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, image, src

i'm trying to display some stored images from the storage folder but it doesn't show!
here is the controller:

```
 public function store(Request $request)
    {
            $templates = new templates([
                "image_path"=>$request->image->hashName(),
                "image_path2"=>$request->image2->hashName(),
                "image_path3"=>$request->image3->hashName(),
 ]);

            $request->image->store('public');
            $request->image2->store('public');
            $request->image3->store('public');
            $templates->save();
```

here's the src images:

```
 @foreach($products as $templates)
              <td> <img src= "storage/app/public/uploads/{{$templates->image_path}}"></img></td>
               <td><img src= "storage/app/public/uploads/{{$templates->image_path2}}"></img></td>
               <td><img src="storage/app/public/uploads/{{$templates->image_path3}}"></img></td>
```

here is the route:

> route::get('/view','App\http\controllers\TemplatesController@index');

and here is the index function:

```
public function index()
    {
        $products = templates::all();

        return view('products.marja', compact('products'));
    }
```

Comment: The controller code you have posted deals with storing the images, but you say you have trouble with displaying them. Can you show the action that's trying to fetch them?

Comment: Not sure but maybe it has something todo with the extra coma at the end of `$templates` that isn't needed?

Comment: As far as I can see in the additional information you posted, the variable you send into view is called `$products`, but you try to use `$templates`. Did you perhaps get an "Undefined variable" notice?

Comment: @Crimin4L That trailing comma is optional, but cannot be the cause of any issues, it's valid syntax for arrays.

Comment: Please share more details. What **exactly** is not working? What have you tried to resolve the problem?

Comment: hi @NicoHaase I uploaded some images and now i'm trying to display it from my Storage folder but it showing a broken link icon.

Comment: "Showing a broken link icon" is already a good start to check for errors. Please add all such explanation to your question by editing it. Also, share more details about what you've tried to resolve the problem

Answer (score 1):

it's finally worked !

i create the symbolic link with:

> php artisan storage:link

then i used this src code :

`<img src="storage/{{$templates->image_path }}" alt=""></img>`

Answer (score 0):

First of all in the **.env** file create a variable named **FILESYSTEM_DRIVER** and set it to **public** like this

```
FILESYSTEM_DRIVER=public
```

and then create symbolic link by run.

```
php artisan storage:link
```

It will copy your `storage` folder into `public` folder then you can access your files just use `asset()`

```
<td> <img src= "{{ asset('storage/........./').$templates->image_path }}"></img></td>
```

It'll work fine.

Comment: I did all what you say but unfotunatly nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

You might see a `storage` folder in your `/public`, and you should notice it's a symlink.
Run the below commands to remove the symlink:

```
cd public
rm storage
cd ..
```

And to create the symbolic link, you may use the `storage:link` Artisan command:

```
php artisan storage:link
```

To view your image in your view use this code:

```
<img src="{{ url('/storage/app/public/uploads/'.$templates->image_path) }}" style="width: 870px; height: 370px;" alt="">
<img src="{{ url('/storage/app/public/uploads/'.$templates->image_path2) }}" style="width: 870px; height: 370px;" alt="">
<img src="{{ url('/storage/app/public/uploads/'.$templates->image_path3) }}" style="width: 870px; height: 370px;" alt="">
```

Comment: it's not a symlink despite that i did all what you say but nothing changed.